# Xamarin.Firebase.Auth wont work when install Xamarin.Firebase.Messages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm struggling to understand why when I install Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging the auth is null in the code below:

```
private void InitFirebaseAuth()
{
     app = FirebaseApp.Instance;

     auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);

     using (var user = auth.CurrentUser)
     {
          if (user != null)
          {
               StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
               Finish();
          }
      }            
}
```

`auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app)` is null, when I uninstall Xamarin.FIrebase.Messaging everything works fine.

I think that there is something with NuGet packages but I can't resolve this problem.

The version of packages like the foto below:

[image]

Any help, please?

EDIT

I reinstalled Visual Studio and now I can see this nuget packages:

[image]

[image]

Nad when I try to downgrade Xamarin.Android.Auth there is this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
>   Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base. Install/reference Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 71.1610.0 directly to project Hearth to resolve this issue. 
>    Hearth -> Xamarin.Firebase.Core 71.1601.0 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Measurement.Connector.Impl 71.1704.0 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl 71.1624.0 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Iid 71.1710.0 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.Interop 71.1601.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (>= 71.1610.0) 
>    Hearth -> Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 60.1142.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (= 60.1142.1).    Hearth  C:\Users\HP\Documents\Projects\Develop\Hearth\Hearth.csproj 1

Comment: Umm, I do not see the supporting packages of both these `NuGets` in your Screenshot :/

Comment: Hi @FreakyAli, I reinstalled Visual Studio and my post, can you please check it?